# How to add a loop cut to an object created using the extrude tool

Tags: edit-mode

I have created an side extension to an existing building starting with a mesh plane and then using extrude (edges) to form the sides.
I want to add timber paneling to match the main building using the same method I did with the building using an edge and the bevel tool however when I attempt to add a loop cut it only adds to the front face.
Is there a way to do this or should I start again using a mesh cube and then remove 'excess' (the area which end up inside the building walls) using boolean?
Here is an image with arrows showing what happens when I add the loop cut (only adds to the front face) and where I want (horizontal) edges on the 3 sides.
I have also included a blender file containing ONLY the building (side) extension

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only adds to the front face because the side face has more than 4 vertices and Blender can't loop cut through a face that is not a quad as it can't guess where to cut. Here are the vertices you need to dissolve (at the bottom you have 2 overlapping vertices):

[image]

Comment: Thanks moonboots. Yes I noticed those vertices earlier (and had no idea how they got there including those on the top face) but did not know that dissolve could remove them. I eventually found them all and dissolved them (2 so close together that they were extremely difficult to see). Once again I have no idea how those extra vertices got there and thanks again. Now I know what dissolve can do.     Please advise when and when not to add @'user name' to a reply so they get notified.

Comment: I've been notified, not sure when you're not actually, but "@" will at least garantee that the person is  ;)

Comment: Thanks.  Once I added @ and someone advised that it was not necessary.

Comment: mmh sometimes I'm not notified of a message of a thread so I'm not sure how it works